# Moving mysql query to model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following mysql query working well. Quick backstory, this lists our customers by total money spent.

```
SELECT  SUM(price) AS money_spent, co.customer_id, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, cu.email_primary
FROM customer_order AS co 
JOIN customer AS cu ON (cu.customer_id = co.customer_id) 
GROUP BY co.customer_id
ORDER BY money_spent DESC
```

I attempted moving this to the customer model, as a scope, and subclass  yet I failed both ways.  I'm somewhat new to rails (formerly client-side) but I think I'm close.  Hoping y'all could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!!!

```
def self.high_rollers  
  options = {
      :select   => "SUM(price) AS money_spent, co.customer_id, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, cu.email_primary",
      :from     => "customer_order AS co",
      :joins    => "customer AS cu ON (cu.customer_id = co.customer_id)",
      :group_by => "co.customer_id",
      :order    => "money_spent DESC"
            }
```

Putting the following code in my index action for this controller works, but definitely doesn't feel like the right approach!

```
@high_bidders = Customer.find_by_sql(<<-SQL
       SELECT  SUM(price) AS money_spent, co.customer_id, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, cu.email_primary
       FROM customer_order AS co 
       JOIN customer AS cu ON (cu.customer_id = co.customer_id) 
       GROUP BY co.customer_id
       ORDER BY money_spent DESC
```

SQL
 )

Comment: "failed" isn't very descriptive.  Do you get an error message?  Do you have other queries that work in this framework?  How are they different?

Comment: Sorry! I got a kend error when trying this. There's definitely something wrong with my syntax though.  When i tried a scope I got an error around group_by. BLAH.  I moved it to a controller using  @high_bidders = Customer.find_by_sql(<<-SQL  and it works; but I know this is poor approach, and this should live in a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your model names are Customer and CustomerOrder. Your table names aren't conventional, I think you already explicitly set table names in models with self.table_name.

```
class CustomerOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  belongs_to :customer

  scope :high_rollers, select("*, SUM(price) AS money_spent").
                       joins(:customer).
                       group(:customer_id).
                       order("money_spent DESC")
end
```

Comment: Yeah table names are all f'd up. Legacy stack I inherited.  I'll try this tomorrow and get back to this post asap.